# Price not showing $ symbol in magento

Tags: magento, catalog

I am facing issue .I tried to replace the price.phtml file but not worked.On all my site `$ dollar` sign is not coming with price.Currently it show price like this `100`.It should be like `$100`.My base currency is dollar.Any one can help how to solve it.Thanks in advance.I have already posted same question magento.stackexchange but didn't get any answer.

Comment: Are you using `$this->getPriceHtml($_product);`?

Comment: i don't know i am using magento 1.8 and price not show any where like cart page or wishlist

Answer (score 0):

`<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); ?>`

or if you want to pass a certain currency code to get currency symbol, then use it:

`<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency('[CURRENCY_CODE]')->getSymbol(); ?>`

Where CURRENCY_CODE should be replaced by currency code of your store:For Example:

`<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency('AUD')->getSymbol(); ?>`

Comment: Thanks for your message.My whole site lacks of `$` sign , not on specific area where i can contacte dollar sign with that.Hope you got my point

Comment: Go to line 68 in app/code/core/Mage/CurrencySymbol/etc/config.xml

<currencysymbol>Mage_CurrencySymbol_Adminhtml</currencysymbol>

Replaced to

<currencysymbol before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mage_CurrencySymbol_Adminhtml</currencysymbol>